# How do Attribute Selectors work in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, css-selectors, javafx-css

In the [**J**avaFX **C**SS **R**eference **G**uide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph), it's made clear that

> JavaFX Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is based on the W3C CSS version 2.1 [[1]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#references) with some additions from current work on version 3 [[2]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#references).

In the JCRG, they often link directly to the W3C's CSS Reference Guide, and such is the case when they talk about selectors.

In the JCRG, they mention [Type Selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#type-selectors), [Class Selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#class-html), and [ID Selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#id-selectors)—they even go so far as to say that they [don't support structural pseudo-classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph)—but nothing is said about [Attribute Selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors).

If JavaFX supports them, how do they work? What does JavaFX consider an attribute? I thought the CSS engine might look at the attributes in the FXML, but then not all scene graphs originate from FXML.

Comment: FXML attributes simply set properties on the corresponding objects. There are no "property selectors" per se, but some nodes will set pseudoclasses if and only if certain properties are set (these are documented in the reference guide you link). So the bottom line is that there is no direct equivalent of attribute selectors unless they map directly to a pseudoclass. Note, of course, that you can always observe a property and set/unset a custom pseudoclass if you need to support CSS based on a property.

Comment: @James_D this should be an answer,  I tested it, There is no attributes selector support in FXML.

Comment: @pdem Yes, I started it as a comment and it kind of grew... let me convert it to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FXML attributes simply set properties on the corresponding objects. There are no "property selectors" per se, but some nodes will set pseudoclasses if and only if certain properties are set (these are documented in the reference guide you link). So the bottom line is that there is no direct equivalent of attribute selectors unless they map directly to a pseudoclass.

Note, of course, that you can always observe a property and set/unset a custom pseudoclass if you need to support CSS based on a property. So it is always possible to recast an attribute selector as a pseudoclass.

So, e.g. suppose you wanted to style a text field differently if it has an `"alignment=CENTER_RIGHT"` attribute. You could do

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
PseudoClass rightAligned = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("right-aligned");
textField.alignmentProperty().addListener((obs, oldAlignment, newAlignment) -> 
    textField.pseudoClassStateChanged(rightAligned, newAlignment == Pos.CENTER_RIGHT));
```

Then in your CSS you just need

```css
.text-field:right-aligned {
    /* style rules */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. Given that JavaFX Structure != HTML Structure, using custom pseudoclasses instead of attribute selectors seems much more intuitive.